# what is the difference between hoding the class object in its reference type and in parents reference type

Tags: java

I have these three class

```
public class Abc
{
    public methAbc()
    {
        System.out.println("parent class method");
    }
}


public class Xyz extends Abc
{
    public methAbc()
    {
        System.out.println("overriden parent class method");
    }

    public methXyz()
    {
        System.out.println("child class method");
    }
}

class Pqr
{
    Xyz childObjChildRef = new Xyz();
    Abc childObjParentdRef = new Xyz(); 
}
```

in class Pqr
what are is the main difference in creating objects in different references

1 : when hold the object in the same class reference
==> then we can call all the methods from the class

2 : when hold the object in the parent class reference
==> then we can call only the overridden methods from the class

Comment: why don't you try calling the methods of the child class using the parent's reference??.. You will get to know the answer...

Comment: @TheLostMind : using parents reference i cant call the child methods

Comment: Apart of the technical details (which method is called), you should be aware of the idea behind object trees. A good example is `Collection` and its sub-types. If you refer to an object as a `Collection` you just see the methods of that interface, i.e. you can `add` and `get` items etc., but you don't care about other details (e.g. wheter it's an `ArrayList`, a `HashSet` or whatever).
*TL;DR*: It simplifies programming.

Comment: See... By using the parent's reference you can call only the parent's methods (if overridden in child class, then the child's class methods will be called...).. The point is , even if you have a childClass object referenced by a parent class reference, then only "reference class's methods are visible".. this is the penalty you pay for being too generic (nicely explained by @Jorge_B below.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In java you are encouraged to use, if possible, the super-type or interface that your concrete type is implementing.  This decouples your code from the actual implementation of the class.

For example: imagine you are writing the main loop of a video-game.  There you write your code using an `Enemy` interface, which has some methods (`collide()`, `shoot()`, `decideNextMovement()`, etc.).  Once you have written your main loop in terms of this interface, it remains as is forever; however, you can always extend your videogame by adding new implementations of the `Enemy` interface (`EnemyShip`, `EnemyMonster`, `EnemyParachuter`, etc.), but you will **never** need to modify your main loop because of that.

This is a design principle in object oriented programming:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle

Answer (score 2):

Variable "childObjParentdRef" is just holding a reference to the instance of Xyz, thus, if you happen to invoke its method "methAbc", you are invoking the overridden method in Xyz although your variable is of type Abc.

So it is important to know that the "methods/behaviors" of the "super type/class" you've instantiated will 'always' be the ones invoked by the compiler even you "box" your object into its "base type/class."

Same works in C#.

Answer (score 2):

Difference between `Xyz childObjChildRef = new Xyz();` and `Abc childObjParentdRef = new Xyz();` is that in first code statement you are creating object of class `Xyz` and assigning to child class reference variable.So you are able to call all methods present in Child class including inherited methods from Parent class.While in second code statement you are creating object of class `Xyz` and assigning it to parent class reference,so you are eligible to call parent class methods inherited or overriden by child class.You can not call child class methods which are not inherited by using parent class reference
Also if you want to maintain loose coupling in code ,then mostly Parent class reference or interface used.